# relationship between creep and hysteresis

Tags: experimental-physics, elasticity

For a particular material that's suspected to be viscoelastic, I observe a hysteresis curve where the difference in elongation between the loading and unloading curves ranges between 5% and 10% for a given load. But, when I perform creep tests, I don't observe any deformation in the material even with an applied stress that's 20% of ultimate tensile strength and after waiting 10 minutes.

I don't know how this is possible as the difference between the loading and unloading curves implies that the Young's Modulus of the material decreases after loading so creep must be observed. You might argue that I didn't wait enough but that also doesn't make sense since for any particular load(L) if you reduce that load by half the extension that's measured is measurably greater(in millimeters) than the extension that you would observe prior to loading L.

So my conclusion is that the Young's Modulus of the material $E$ must decrease almost immediately after loading and so creep must be observed if hysteresis is observed.

Comment: I don't see a question here - please clarify. As a comment, I do not agree that 'creep must be observed' in a viscoelastic material. Why do you think that?

Comment: @JonCuster I didn't say that creep must be observed in a viscoelastic material but I think that creep must be observed if hysteresis is observed since the Young's Modulus decreases.